# How can I properly remove an event handler in a JavaScript class function?

Tags: javascript, events, addeventlistener

I hope you can help.

I've stripped down the code to make the question easier to read.

I have a button that loads a video modal and fires a `GET` request.

```
export default class Videos {

  constructor() {
    this.button1 = document.getElementById('button1');
    this.button2 = document.getElementById('button2');
    this.button3 = document.getElementById('button3');
  }

  init() {
    this.populateModal();
  }

  populateModal(el) {

    this.button1.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
      e.preventDefault();
      this.videoLoadHandler(value);
    });

    this.button2.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
      e.preventDefault();
      this.videoLoadHandler(value);
    });

    this.button3.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
      e.preventDefault();
      this.videoLoadHandler(value);
    });

  }

  videoLoadHandler(e,value){
    console.log("video Plays and get request happens");
  }

}
```

The video plays and the get request works perfectly as expected.

The `populateModal` function will be fired every time specific buttons are click. This means that the `videoLoadHandler` function is firing multiple times the more the `populateModal` function is fired and I believe it's because a new event listener is being created and stacking / firing multiple times for each newly created event listner. I was almost able to fix it with this:

```
var self = this;
this.button1.addEventListener("click", function test(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  self.videoLoadHandler(e,cta_url2,hash);
  self.button2.removeEventListener("click", test);
});
```

The issue here is that the event listener is removed and so the `e.preventDefault()` no longer fires after the initial button click.

What is the ideal way to achieve this or simply remove an event listener BEFORE creating the same one in a javascript class?

Your help is much appreciated.
Please and thank you.
Moe.

Comment: Are you sure `self.button2.removeEventListener("click", test);` actually removed the eventListener?

Comment: it would, @zer00ne

Comment: @zer00ne I am certain. The element is an a tag and once the function runs the first time, the e.preventDefault no longer fires and the a tag directs the user away from the page.

Comment: Why don’t you simply assign a new event handler that only does what you want done on the subsequent clicks and then remove the first event handler?

Comment: @ScottMarcus That is exactly what I would like to do. Having trouble getting my head around doing it. I found a solution but not sure if it's ideal. Seems to work perfectly: Instead of using `addEventHandler` syntax I used `this.button2.click = function() {e.preventDefault();}`. This seems to remove the need to add and remove event Handlers. Is this a valid method?

Comment: @Moe-Joe my bad didn't notice this: `function test(e){...`

Comment: That’s reverting to the old way and not advised.  just set up a second one inside the first and then remove the first. It’s actually pretty simple.